# populate array(list) to send a call from c# to php

Tags: c#

So I'm passing parameters from unity to a PHP API and all are fine but now I want to pass it as an array, so in this method I have declared my lists and trying to send the requests with the correct parameters

`tokenID`, `address`, and `value` (the last 3) need to be populated from the lists declared, but I'm stuck on how to do that.

any help appreciated

```
public List<string> recipientAdvancedAddress = new List<string>();
public List<string> tokenAdvancedSend = new List<string>();
public List<string> valueAdvancedSend = new List<string>();

public void Send()
{
    StartCoroutine(SendAsync(userSession, senderAdvancedID, tokenAdvancedSend, recipientAdvancedAddress, valueAdvancedSend));
}

IEnumerator SendAsync(string session, int senderID, List<string> tokenID, List<string> addresses, List<string> value)
{
    CryptoFilter cryptoFilter = new CryptoFilter();
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("action", "advancedSendFT");
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("session", session);
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("senderID", $"{senderID}");
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("tokenID", tokenID);
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("addresses", addresses);
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("value", value);

    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post($"http://{SERVER_ADDR}/tsd/api.php", cryptoFilter.GetRequestPayload()))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            var result = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
            // Decrypt the response from the server.
            result = cryptoFilter.GetResponsePayload(result);
            sendItem data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sendItem>(result);
            if (!data.error)
                txID = data.id;
        }

}
```

this is the error: https://i.ibb.co/frNR5tF/error.png

and this is the method in the CryptoFilter.cs

```
class CryptoFilter
{

    // Encrypt & Decrypt Engine
    AES256 aes = new AES256();

    // Request parameters
    Dictionary<string, string> request = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    /*
     *
     * Add a parameter.
     * 
     */
    public void AddParam(string name, string value)
    {
        if (value != "")
            request.Add(name, value);
    }

    /*
     *
     * Get the encrypted request string.
     * 
     */
    public string GetRequestPayload()
    {
        string plain = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        return aes.EncryptString(plain);
    }

    /*
     *
     * Get the decrypted response string.
     * 
     */
    public string GetResponsePayload(string encrypted)
    {
        return aes.DecryptString(encrypted);
    }

}
```

Btw, couldn't I do a foreach in the main script?

this is how the php is sent btw:

```
CreateEnjinRequest(
identity_id: YOUR_IDENTITY_ID,
type: ADVANCED_SEND,
advanced_send_token_data: {transfers: [
{tokenID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", addresses: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", value:"1" },
{tokenID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", addresses: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", value:"1" }
]})
```

so if I have 1 tokenID it's fine, but when I need to send 2 tokenID's to 2 different addresses is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: What's CryptoFilter?

Comment: It's used for cryptography purposes

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What does `CryptoFilter` do? How does this sending to a PHP API actually happen? In what format does this API expect to receive an array? What is your code now sending that doesn't match what is expected?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, CryptoFilter is another script which is used for decrypt/encrypt data. the first 3 work just fine (the ones that doesnt need a List, my requirement is how to make 

cryptoFilter.AddParam("tokenID", tokenID);
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("addresses", addresses);
    cryptoFilter.AddParam("value", value);

 to accept input from the arrays

Comment: here is the error on the 3 vars: https://i.ibb.co/frNR5tF/error.png

Comment: Does CryptoFilter only accept strings for param values?

Comment: correct, it doesn't really play much of a role to my errors I guess

Comment: Maybe you could try to serialize the list with JSON, join the strings yourself using String.Join in case you know a field seperator that you can use or just don't use lists and send the requests seperately.

Comment: it is important to send them all at once. This is what I m trying to do, to send and array back to the php

Comment: added more info in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an overload for the AddParam method:

```
AddParam(List<string>)
```

Or a generic version:

```
AddParam(List<T>)
```

Or even:

```
AddParam(Collection<T>)
```

I think I don't really understand what you're asking but within this method, you could maybe just loop through the items and do with them whatever you're already doing.

Edit: Looks like you need a json in the end. You can use Unity's built-in serialization for this. First make a class that represent the DTO (data transfer object) and then serialize it so it's a json string.

```
[Serializable]
public class CryptoFilter
{
    public string action;
    // other string fields

    public List<string> addresses;
    // other string list fields

    public CryptoFilter(string action, List<string> addresses)
    {
        this.action = action;
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
CryptoFilter cryptoFilter = new CryptoFilter(...);
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(cryptoFilter);
```

Edit: A string to string dictionary as request won't work for lists. Use a serializable class like the one I posted for this. Just call it Request or so instead of CryptoFilter. Then create the object and set it to the CryptoFilter once instead of calling AddParam multiple times.

Comment: added to my original post

Comment: thanks for your answer, well I just edited my post again to include all the script, I already decerialize jason and it works fine, what I haven't be able to achieve yet is to send parameteris via a list, which is what I'm trying to do. Really sorry if I havent described my issue correctly from the begining.

Will try what you suggested for the CryptoFilter script

Comment: yeah it doesn't work in my already created appliance, but I thing you are on something with the CryptoFilter.cs changes, if you have the time can you check the full phpFunctions class and see what alternation might need to be made?

Comment: @DownNode Edited again :P